# pros and cons of adding a server to a domain controller?

Tags: sql, windows, dns, active-directory, windows-server

I'm starting on this and I would like to know the pros and cons of adding my server (Windows server 2016) to a domain controller (AD DS).
We have 4 virtualized machines on it with hyper-V: 1st one with SQL server, 2nd with a fileserver, 3rd with the domain controller and the last one with financial accounting services.

what should i be careful with?

Thank you!!

Comment: Check domain controller advantage : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/200843/domain-controller-avantage.html and for drawback check this https://serverfault.com/questions/185990/what-are-the-drawbacks-of-making-all-of-my-windows-servers-domain-controllers

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.